# CreateJobObject behaviour when already inside a job

Tags: c, winapi

My scenario: I have a C program in Windows that, in running time, corresponds to  `process A`; it needs to start another process (`process B`) and monitor it so that, under some external event (say, lock file removed) it can terminate `B` and all its eventual children (processes started by `B`).

My approach was to place `B` into a job created with [CreateJobObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409(v=vs.85).aspx), so that process `A` can terminate it (together with its children) with [TerminateJobObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686709(v=vs.85).aspx) - and then it can terminate itself.

```
HANDLE jobHandle = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL); // creates job
...
res=CreateProcess(NULL,cmdline, .... &pi);  // creates process B
AssignProcessToJobObject(jobHandle,pi.hProcess); // add process B to job
...
if(...)  { 
    TerminateJobObject(jobHandle,exitCode);  // terminate job: process B and children
    ....
}
```

This works. Except that, under certain circumstances [*] the process `A` happens to be already included in a job. In this case `CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL)` does not create a new job, but it returns the current one - which is not what I want.

How do create a wholly new job?

I don't want to rely on nested jobs, because I want to support Windows 7.

[*] I'm looking at you, Eclipse - but that does not matter much now.

Comment: Read the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448388(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As I stated in the question, I cannot use nested jobs,

Comment: Well then you'll just have to live with it. Once a process is in a job, it stays there. Again as documented.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Please read the question. I don't want to take a process out of a job. I want to create a new process and place it in a new job

Comment: You could try `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB`, although this will only work if the parent has explicitly enabled it.  Or you could try [this approach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643) (or similar) to get Explorer to launch the new process on your behalf.  (Or perhaps another copy of your executable, which can then launch the child process in the usual way.)

Comment: Incidentally, are you sure that CreateJobObject is returning the existing job?  I've never seen that behaviour, usually you just get an error when attempting to assign the new job to the process.  (Although if that *is* happening it potentially gives you another out: you could use it to set `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK` even if the parent doesn't.)

Comment: You are wanting to move process A into a new job and that's what can't be done.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan For second time: I don't want "to move process A into a new job". I want process A to create a new (dissociated) job and a (dissociated) process B , and then place B into the new process.

Comment: I thought you wanted for when A terminates, that its children do too. You want instead for termination of B to lead to B's children being terminated. So you need `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB`.

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

The solution was to add the flag `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` to the `CreateProcess` call:

```
res=CreateProcess(NULL,cmdline,   NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                  NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                  FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                  CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB,  // don't place inside old job
                  NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                  NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
                  &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                  &pi );           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
```

Two caveats:

- For this to work, the old job must have the `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK` flag enabled - it was in my case.
- I had wrongly believed that, in my original code, the call `CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL)` returned the old job and that's why the new process ended in the old job - if that were true, then this solution would not work. But it was not true, what happened was that `AssignProcessToJobObject` failed (my fault for not checking return code) because the newly created process was already placed in the old job. `CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL)` returns a new job.

Comment: Incidentally, you should also specify `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and resume the process after adding it to the job.  Otherwise there is a potential race condition where B starts a subprocess before you've called AssignProcessToJobObject().

Comment: @HarryJohnston Good point, Harry (that's the kind of thing we expect to get and share here in SO), thanks.